# angular-file-upload provisional headers are not sent in IE browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, request-headers, angular-file-upload

I am using angular-file-upload in my application especially for IE compatability, before I have Used Formdata to upload files,

Its working fine chrome, but its not working in IE9+ browser, The problem is the provisional headers set by me are not sent to server which causes the problem

Can anyone helpme on the same?
[image: In CHROME]
[image: IN IE BROWSER]

Thanks and Regards,
Satish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the problem with angular-file-upload directives, Its not support custom headers to send to backend , so its skipping my provisional headers in IE